# Can we have a way to integrate control-m with mule?

Tags: mule

We have a requirement where we want mule to be invoked with fixed frequency we want to utilise control-m for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Control-M agent is running on your Mule ESB server, then you can use it to invoke a script which uses curl to invoke an http inbound endpoint flow, or to send a JMS message for a Mule flow with a JMS inbound endpoint, or place a file in a directory for a file inbound endpoint, etc... You get the idea, right? Any of the inbound endpoints are a possible candidate for the kickoff. Whether you are running Mule under Windows or Nix is another question as well, but it will work either way with some mods as to the scripting approach.